# Finding the pending or last event in the event bubbling using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to identify the last event or number of pending events in an event bubbling phase using the jQuery event object?

Ex: (Link: http://jsfiddle.net/hNTQc/)

HTML

```
<div>
    Div
    <p>
        Paragraph
        <br>
        <br>
        <span>
            Span
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").click(function(event){
    alert("Spam");
  });
  $("p").click(function(event){
    alert("P");
  });
  $("div").click(function(){
     alert("Div");
  });
});
```

Expected Output (Pending Events) -->  Clicked Element

- 2 --> span
- 1 --> p
- 0 --> div

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Answer (score 2):

The click event is triggered with the exact same event object on each of the elements along the bubbling route.  You can check this by adding a property to the event low in the chain and checking for that value higher up.  In this sense, there are no "pending events", just one event that triggers on multiple elements.

jQuery allows you to get all of the ancestors of an element within the dom using `$(el).parents()`.  Then you can manually check for event handlers bound to those elements.  The API for that is `$._data(element, "events")` though this is a private API and may change in future versions.

Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish?  There may be a better way.

Comment: Actually, I've an Unordered List (ul-li combination, with spans, buttons, etc), which is linked with a jQuery plugin. In that plugin I've done actions/cleanups at every level/trigger of the event bubble (changing the sibling properties up the tree hierarchy at every stage). But at the end of this bubbling sequence(i.e,finding the last event) I need to trigger an event to perform the next set of actions based on the updated state of the tree. But I'm not able to get the end of the trigger sequence because the properties associated with the ul-li is the same, as the code is auto generated.

Comment: So when the top most click handler is running you need to know you are the last one?  Can you do `$(this).parents('ul, li').length === 0` or some similar contextual test?

Comment: You might also be able to setTimeout() from within the click handlers but store it within a closure so each handler can see the same variable.  In each handler only set the timeout if it isn't already set.  I believe the click handlers will all run to completion, then the stack will return and clear and the timeout should run afterward.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the direction of using parents, thats kinda clicked. I don't have any 'div' usage inside the ul-li combination or the plugin(it is independent of div). So for my case the condition `if (1 == $(evnt.currentTarget).parentsUntil('div').length)` will do the work perfectly :)